# Underscore error when running karma + jasmine test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, marionette, karma-jasmine

I'm new with frontend code testing. I have a strange error when running karma + jasmine tests over my js MarionetteJs app. I think it might be because underscore templates are not loaded yet when I'm defining my Marionette views.

My karma.conf.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        exclude: ["*.jst"],
        logLevel: 'LOG_DEBUG',
        reporters: ['progress'],
        preprocessors: {
            'tests/unit/**/test_*.js': ['browserify']
        },
        colors: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        plugins: [
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-browserify',
            'karma-jasmine-ajax',
            'karma-jasmine-jquery',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
        ],
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [
                'browserify-jst',
                'browserify-shim',
                'browserify-istanbul'
            ]
        },
        files: [
            'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',
            'tests/unit/**/test_*.js'
        ]
    });
};
```

This is just a dummy test that I'm trying to run:

```
'use strict';

var CompanyListView = require('../../company_list.js');

$(function () {
    describe("A page", function () {
        it("contains login form", function () {            
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Error happens during requiring `company_list.js` file:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'text.replace')
  at /tmp/082eb28c15575edda85ae0f9ce2019a6.browserify:17883:0 <- node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:1431:0
```

company_list.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var tplCompany = require('../templates/company_list.jst');

module.exports = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: _.template(tplCompany, {variable: 'data'}),
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess it can't load `var tplCompany = require('../templates/company_list.jst');` and passes `undefined` to `_.template`, so underscore throws an error.

Comment: No, when it can not load any file, browserify throws something like this: ERROR [framework.browserify]: Error: Cannot find module 'pages/app/js/seller/templates/company_list.jst' from '/seller/views'

Comment: But does the variable `tplCompany` has an actual value before it is passed to `_.template`?

Comment: When I''m running the app in browser, it has correct value (contains html), but when I'm running the jasmine test with karma, it does not output anything in my terminal, so, I don't know :( And I can not find any solution to debug that.

Comment: Just `console.log('HERE', tplCompany)` should print the result to a terminal (add some noticeable string like `HERE` in case if variable is empty so you won't see anything).  By the way, I see an interesting option in your karma.conf.js: `exclude: ["*.jst"]`, could it be the reason of templates not loading?

Comment: Nope, exclude files does not make any sense here, pls see my answer for the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was in karma.conf.js:

```
transform: [
      'browserify-jst',
      'browserify-shim',
      'browserify-istanbul'
]
```

Must be:

```
transform: [
    ['stringify', {extensions: ['.html', '.jst'], minify: false}],
    'browserify-shim',
    'browserify-istanbul'
]
```